# Select box: how to populate days php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Recently i ask [how to populate years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370583/select-box-how-to-populate-years-php) and i thought that i have all the answer i need. Thing is that i have a new problem with days. The problem seems to be more of mysql than php. In my table users, birthday field, i put "date" as the type which is in this format: 0000-00-00. Now when i use the current select box "day", it inserts 2 instead of 02 and then compromises the whole format when i join $year.$month.$day giving me and output like 1988-11-. How can i solve this? This is the code for days (the year is similar, and it's in the link above). Thanks

```
<? 
$bday = $r['birthday'];
$part = explode("-", $bday);
$year = $part[0];
$month = $part[1];
$day = $part[2]; ?>
<select name="day">
    <? for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){?>
    <option value="<? echo $i. '"'; if ($day == $i) {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>"><?echo $i;?></option>  <? }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh i can't change mysql type now because it already have real user information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$bday = $r['birthday'];
$part = explode("-", $bday);
$year = $part[0];
$month = $part[1];
$day = $part[2]; ?>
<select name="day">
    <? for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){?>
    <option value="<? echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '"'; if ($day == $i) {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>"><?echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?></option>  <? }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Worked great, haha never knew of a str_pad, guess i need to read more php man. Thanks

Comment: You can study further from here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php. Good luck friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="day">
    <? for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){?>
    <option value="<? echo ($i < 10 ? '0' . $i : $i). '"'; if ($day == $i) {echo 'selected="selected"';}?>"><?echo $i;?></option>  <? }?>
</select>
```